# What protocol provider to connect to JMX on WebSphere via SOAP?

Tags: soap, websphere, jmx

I'd like to connect to the JMX server on a WebSphere application server instance using a SOAP over HTTP connector but I don't know where to find a compatible SOAP protocol provider.

I get a `MalformedURLException` when using a JMXServiceURL starting `service:jmx:soap:...` that says `Unsupported protocol: soap`. What jar(s)/protocol provider string do I need to include?

---

Update: I am playing with a standalone Java client.

Comment: Where are you trying to connect from ? (another WAS, standlone Java, Thin Client, etc)

Comment: Updated question to clarify.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't use it as an admin client for WAS ?

Comment: I would like a generic approach that doesn't *just* work for WAS, so I've been focussing on using JMXServiceURLs to define service endpoints, not IBM's AdminClient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, IBM only provides a proprietary API to connect with SOAP over HTTP. They don't provide an implementation of the standard JMX API for that protocol. I faced the same issue and I developed such a connector (which is basically a thin JMX compliant wrapper around IBM's proprietary API), which is now available as Open Source. You can find more information here:

https://github.com/kszbcss/xm4was/wiki/JmxClientConnector

The following document describes how to set up a standard JMX tool (VisualVM) to use that connector:

https://github.com/kszbcss/xm4was/wiki/VisualVMHowTo

As you can see from these documents, after adding the relevant JARs to the class path and setting the necessary system properties, you would simply connect using `wssoap` as protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Check that in the path `Application servers > <server_name> > Administration services > JMX connectors` the relative **SOAPConnector** exists and is **Enabled**.

Refer at [Infocenter](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/cjmx_overview.html) for more information.

Comment: My test doesn't appear to be attempting to connect at all (due to the lack of anything to implement a soap transport on the client side?) thus the question. The documentation provided by IBM doesn't seem to provide this information, instead providing examples of use of a proprietary "AdminClient". I don't want to use a proprietary interface, I want to use the standard JMX approach that will also work for non-WebSphere stuff.

Comment: Maybe the following is more helpful even if it refers to RMI-IIOP Connection not SOAP: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.nd.doc%2Finfo%2Fae%2Fae%2Ftjmx_develop_jsr160.html

Comment: The problem is that the SOAP connector is used a completely different way to the RMI-IIOP connector. I'm not downvoting though, as your answer seems like a reasonable troubleshooting step to take.